# Setter/getter for class property (Object.assign)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to be trigger a setter on a class property:

```
class Example {
    prop = { default: 'default', color: 'red' };

    set prop(value) {
        // this.prop will be undefined as the setter overrides the class property)
        Object.assign(this.prop, value);
    }
}

const myExample = Example();
myExample.prop.default = 'new';

// Trying to get prop = { default: 'new', color: 'red' }
```

The setter will override prop I believe, how could I specify a default object value? Should I store the class property prop as like _prop?

Comment: Add a corresponding getter and store it in a property with a different name.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, I editted my question with that solution just now :) Is there any cleaner way to do this or is this the correct way? I've been reading on Object.defineProperty but don't know whether that's the right solution here.

Comment: class only allow method definitions. Not data properties.

Comment: @oriol You mean class doesn't allow properties? It does if you're using es and babel.

Comment: @JohnSmith I think they refer to the fact that it's not standardised yet.

Comment: @zerkms hm okay, but I'm going to use them for my project. I guess I'll just use _prop for the default value if there's no other way.

Comment: @JohnSmith Well, you tagged ES6 and definitely it's not allowed in ES6. Neither in ES7.

Comment: @Oriol I kind of just meant ES in general, I removed it from the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define the accessors manually in the constructor:

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {
    var prop = { default: 'default', color: 'red' };
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'prop', {
      get() { return prop; },
      set(value) { Object.assign(prop, value); }
    });
  }
}
const myExample = new Example();
console.log(myExample.prop);
myExample.prop = {foo: "bar"};
console.log(myExample.prop);
```

If you don't mind `prop` being public, you could move the accessors outside the constructor, and share them among all instances:

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this._prop = { default: 'default', color: 'red' };
  }
  get prop() { return this._prop; }
  set prop(value) { Object.assign(this._prop, value); }
}
const myExample = new Example();
console.log(myExample.prop);
myExample.prop = {foo: "bar"};
console.log(myExample.prop);
```

Comment: What would be the advantages of this approach over using class properties? I don't really like putting a ton of stuff in constructors.

Comment: @JohnSmith Because you must store the data somewhere, and class definitions only allow method definitions, not data properties. You can move the accessors outside the constructor, though.

Comment: Okay, but try to understand that I'm using class properties for this project, it's not like I'm going to switch everything because something isn't standarized yet. What would be the advantages of this approach?

Comment: @JohnSmith What makes you thing it will eventually become standard?

Comment: I think classes need properties... but you're missing the point don't you think? I'll gladly accept your answer which is standarized, but I'm looking for a non-standarized solution. I don't know much about defineProperty and I'm asking whether there is an advantage, not whether trying to get into a debate on what will become standard...

Comment: @JohnSmith Babel moves assignments inside the constructor. [So it's the same](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?&evaluate=true&presets=stage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&code=class%20Example%20%7B%0A%20%20_prop%20%3D%20%7B%20default%3A%20%27default%27%2C%20color%3A%20%27red%27%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20get%20prop()%20%7B%20return%20this._prop%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20set%20prop(value)%20%7B%20Object.assign(this._prop%2C%20value)%3B%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aconst%20myExample%20%3D%20new%20Example()%3B%0Aconsole.log(myExample.prop)%3B%0AmyExample.prop%20%3D%20%7Bfoo%3A%20%22bar%22%7D%3B%0Aconsole.log(myExample.prop)%3B).

Comment: Ah, `defineProperty` just defines the getter and the setter to an existing object. It's also basically the same, but in that example I defined them to the instance instead of to the prototype.

Comment: sorry I deleted my previous comment Thanks, I probably should have been more specific in my comments in what I was looking for.